# login to bteq in solaris one liner

Tags: teradata, solaris, sunos

can any one please help me with the command to login to teradata in solaris using bteq

general command to login is

```
.LOGON $TDPID/$username,$password;
```

but this is not working in solaris. it says below

> *** Error:  Invalid logon!

teradata version installed -13.10.00.02

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is clearly not a question about programming and should be directed to Teradata support or a Teradata forum.

Comment: It should be the same on any client OS. `.LOGON $TDPID/$username,$password;` is for batch mode, in interactive mode it's `.LOGON $TDPID/$username;` and then it's asking for the password.